# How to create sockjs (SockJS - WebSocket emulation) or Shoe standalone server (node.js)?

Tags: node.js, sockjs, dnode

Does anyone know how to create [sockjs-node](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node) (SockJS - WebSocket emulation) or [Shoe](https://github.com/substack/shoe) standalone server?

Is it possible to crate without http Server?

Just need to exchange data with `dnode`, and static pages are not necessary.

For instance, when I do on node server side:

```
var shoe = require('shoe');
var dnode = require('dnode');
var http = require('http');


var server = http
    .createServer()
    .listen(9999);

var echo = shoe
    .createServer()
    .on('connection', function(c)
    {
        var d = dnode(
        {
            test: function()
            {
                console.log('--------');
            }
        });

        c
            .on('data', function(message)
            {
                c.write(message);
            })
            .on('close', function() {});

        c
            .pipe(d)
            .pipe(c);

        c.on('close', function() {});
    })
    .installHandlers(server,
    {
        prefix: '/dnode'
    });
```

The following code(Client Side)

```
var d = dnode()
    .on('remote', function(remote)
    {
        remote.test();
    });

d
    .pipe(shoe('http://localhost/dnode'))
    .pipe(d);
```

Fails with the following error:(Chrome)

```
GET http://localhost/dnode/info  app.bundle.js:14681
AbstractXHRObject._start app.bundle.js:14681
(anonymous function)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not find a way with SockJS or Shoe, so I switched with [websocket-stream](https://github.com/maxogden/websocket-stream).

Here's a working code:

**node server**

```
'use strict';

var ws = require('ws');
var websocketStream = require('websocket-stream');
var dnode = require('dnode');
var http = require('http');

var HTTPserver = http
    .createServer()
    .listen(9999);

var WSserver = new ws.Server(
{
    server: HTTPserver
});

WSserver
    .on('connection', function(s)
    {
        var c = websocketStream(s);
        var d = dnode(
        {
            test: function(f)
            {
                console.log('--------');
                f('hello');
            }
        });

        c
            .pipe(d)
            .pipe(c);
    });
```

**browser client**

```
'use strict';

var websocketStream = require('websocket-stream');
var dnode = require('dnode');

var c = websocketStream('ws://localhost:9999');
var d = dnode()
    .on('remote', function(remote)
    {
        remote.test(function(msg)
        {
            alert(msg);
        });
    });

c
    .pipe(d)
    .pipe(c);
```